# How do I check file size in Python?

Tags: python, file

How do I get the size of a file in Python?

Answer (score 1060, accepted):

You need the [`st_size`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat_result.st_size) property of [the object returned by `os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat_result). You can get it by either using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html) (Python 3.4+):

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path('somefile.txt').stat()
os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=6419862, st_dev=16777220, st_nlink=1, st_uid=501, st_gid=20, st_size=1564, st_atime=1584299303, st_mtime=1584299400, st_ctime=1584299400)
>>> Path('somefile.txt').stat().st_size
1564
```

or using [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.stat('somefile.txt')
os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=6419862, st_dev=16777220, st_nlink=1, st_uid=501, st_gid=20, st_size=1564, st_atime=1584299303, st_mtime=1584299400, st_ctime=1584299400)
>>> os.stat('somefile.txt').st_size
1564
```

Output is in bytes.

Comment: @josch - yes, this is nice, for the "size on disk" you can multiply `stat_result.st_blocks` by the block size, but I'm still searching how to get it programmatically and cross-platform (not via `tune2fs` etc.)

Comment: @TomaszGandor now `st_blocks` is defined as "Number of 512-byte blocks allocated for file", so you don't have to get the block size.

Answer (score 1489):

Use [`os.path.getsize`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.getsize("/path/to/file.mp3")
2071611
```

The output is in bytes.

Comment: Note: the implementation of `os.path.getsize` is simply `return os.stat(filename).st_size`

Comment: So is there a minute performance loss from using os.path.getsize as opposed to os.stat(file).st_size?

Comment: @wordsforthewise measure it! ~150 ns in my computer.

Comment: @wordsforthewise this is more of an issue if you also want to get other things about the file (modification time, type of file, e.g.) -- then you might as well get it all from a single system call via `os.stat`. Then the difference could run into a substantial number of microseconds :-)

Comment: Another advantage of directly using `os.stat()` is, that it accepts filenames relative to a directory file descriptor `dir_fd` as in `os.stat(relname, dir_fd=mydirfd).st_size`, while `os.path.getsize()` does not. When parsing through directory trees, `dir_fd` can be a large advantage.

Answer (score 150):

The other answers work for real files, but if you need something that works for "file-like objects", try this:

```
# f is a file-like object. 
f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
size = f.tell()
```

It works for real files and StringIO's, in my limited testing. (Python 2.7.3.) The "file-like object" API isn't really a rigorous interface, of course, but the [API documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) suggests that file-like objects should support `seek()` and `tell()`.

**Edit**

Another difference between this and `os.stat()` is that you can `stat()` a file even if you don't have permission to read it. Obviously the seek/tell approach won't work unless you have read permission.

**Edit 2**

At Jonathon's suggestion, here's a paranoid version. (The version above leaves the file pointer at the end of the file, so if you were to try to read from the file, you'd get zero bytes back!)

```
# f is a file-like object. 
old_file_position = f.tell()
f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
size = f.tell()
f.seek(old_file_position, os.SEEK_SET)
```

Comment: And for the last line, if ```os``` isn't used: ```f.seek(old_file_position, 0)```

Comment: If you use integer literals instead of named variables, you are torturing anybody that has to maintain your code. There's no compelling reason not to import `os`.

Comment: Apparently this is at least a little risky, depending on how Python implements `#seek()`: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek%28%29+and+ftell%28%29+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file

Answer (score 110):

```
import os


def convert_bytes(num):
    """
    this function will convert bytes to MB.... GB... etc
    """
    for x in ['bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB']:
        if num < 1024.0:
            return "%3.1f %s" % (num, x)
        num /= 1024.0


def file_size(file_path):
    """
    this function will return the file size
    """
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        file_info = os.stat(file_path)
        return convert_bytes(file_info.st_size)


# Lets check the file size of MS Paint exe 
# or you can use any file path
file_path = r"C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe"
print file_size(file_path)
```

Result:

```
6.1 MB
```

Comment: Line 10 can be changed to `return f'{num:.1f} {x}'` in Python >= 3.5.

Comment: thank you Matt M., slight update, line 10 can be changed to `return f'{num}{unit}' if unit == 'bytes' else f'{num:.1f}{unit}' ` in Python >= 3.5

Comment: `file_info = os.stat(file_path).st_size`

Answer (score 67):

Using `pathlib` ([added in Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) or a backport available on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2)):

```
from pathlib import Path
file = Path() / 'doc.txt'  # or Path('./doc.txt')
size = file.stat().st_size
```

This is really only an interface around `os.stat`, but using `pathlib` provides an easy way to access other file related operations.

Answer (score 30):

There is a `bitshift` trick I use if I want to to convert from `bytes` to any other unit. If you do a right shift by `10` you basically shift it by an order (multiple).

> Example:  `5GB are 5368709120 bytes`

```
print (5368709120 >> 10)  # 5242880 kilobytes (kB)
print (5368709120 >> 20 ) # 5120 megabytes (MB)
print (5368709120 >> 30 ) # 5 gigabytes (GB)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The question is about finding the size of a file, not about formatting the result for human consumption.

Comment: These numbers are wrong and thus confusing. 5GB is 5e9 bytes. Is this supposed to be some sort of human-readable approximation? Where would you even use something like this?

Comment: 1-bit=>2
...
2-bits=>4
...
3-bits=>8
...
4-bits=>16
...
5-bits=>32
...
6-bits=>64
...
7-bits=>128
...
8-bits=>256
...
9-bits=>512
...
10-bits=>1024
...
1024 bytes is 1kB
...
=> 20-bits => 1024 * 1024 = 1,048,576bytes, which is 1024kB, and 1MB...
=> 30-bits => 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 1,073,741,824 bytes, which is 1,048,576 kB, and 1024MB, and 1GB
… You have confused scientific notation and decimal places with the binary/base-2 representation used in computing.
5x9 = 5 x 10^9 = 5,000,000,000

Comment: Guys, he hasn't *confused* anything... he's just given an approximation, which is evident when he says "basically".  2^10 is approx. 10^3.  In fact, this approximation is so common that [it has a name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte): *Mebi*, *Gibi*, and *Tebi* are Mega, Giga, and Tera, respectively. Regarding not answering the question, @WillManley , you have a fair point there!  ;-p

Answer (score 18):

we have two options Both include importing os module

1)

```py
import os
os.stat("/path/to/file").st_size
```

as `os.stat()` function returns an object which contains so many headers including file created time and last modified time etc.. among them `st_size` gives the exact size of the file.
File path can be either absolute or relative.

2)
In this, we have to provide the exact file path, File path can be either relative or absolute.

```py
import os
os.path.getsize("path of file")
```

Comment: os.path.getsize works with a relative path

Answer (score 9):

Strictly sticking to the question, the Python code (+ pseudo-code) would be:

```
import os
file_path = r"<path to your file>"
if os.stat(file_path).st_size > 0:
    <send an email to somebody>
else:
    <continue to other things>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `stat()` method from the `os` module. You can provide it with a path in the form of a string, bytes or even a PathLike object. It works with file descriptors as well.

```
import os

res = os.stat(filename)

res.st_size # this variable contains the size of the file in bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another self-explanatory example. With this, bytes will be converted into MBs, GBs, or TBs automatically.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from psutil._common import bytes2human

def get_readable_filesize(text_file: Path):
    return bytes2human(text_file.stat().st_size)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    current_file = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
    print(get_readable_filesize(current_file / 'file.txt'))
```

Answer (score -3):

```
#Get file size , print it , process it...
#Os.stat will provide the file size in (.st_size) property. 
#The file size will be shown in bytes.

import os

fsize=os.stat('filepath')
print('size:' + fsize.st_size.__str__())

#check if the file size is less than 10 MB

if fsize.st_size < 10000000:
    process it ....
```