# How do I get a block device's size correctly in go?

Tags: go

EDITED: as @abhink pointed out, was not invoking `Size()`.

I tried two different go methods, and then compared to `df`. Of course, all 3 give different results:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    disk := "/dev/sda1"
    statout, err := os.Stat(disk)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("Error %x", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    println("os.Stat Size   : ", statout.Size())

    var stat syscall.Statfs_t
    syscall.Statfs(disk, &stat)
    println("syscall.Statfs_t Type: ",  stat.Type)
    println("syscall.Statfs_t Bsize: ",  stat.Bsize)
    println("syscall.Statfs_t Blocks: ",  stat.Blocks)
}
```

Running the programs:

```
$ main
os.Stat Size   :  0
syscall.Statfs_t Type: 16914836
syscall.Statfs_t Bsize: 4096
syscall.Statfs_t Blocks: 2560
```

And df:

```
$ df /dev/sda1
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             65792556  43694068  18726712  70% /var
```

Net:

- `os.Stat()` gives `0` which it is not, but might be an OS issue.
- `syscall.Statfs()` gives 2560 blocks * 4096 block size = `10,485,760`. More realistic, but still incorrect
- `df` gives 65792556 1K-blocks * 1024 bytes / K = `67,371,577,344`

How do I reliably get the size of a block device without mounting it?

Essentially, I am looking for the equivalent of the `ioctl` call on the device.

```
ioctl(fd,BLKGETSIZE64,&size)
```

Comment: `os.Stat` returns an `os.FileInfo` type which is an interface type. `Size` is a method on the returned type, not a field. `0xc420031f58` is the address of the function `Size`. https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo

Comment: Sidenote: `fmt.Errorf` does not what you think it does. Much like printing an os.FileInfos Size field. How about looking up the documentation for all functions/methods used?

Comment: Oh, oops. I was supposed to do `Size()`. Nice catch.

Comment: Well, `Size()` returns `0`, so that certainly isn't it. I believe that is more of an OS thing, since `# stat /dev/sda1` gives `Size: 0`

Comment: "Sidenote: fmt.Errorf does not..." I don't particularly care, @volker. Copy-paste and edit the minimum necessary to show what works/doesn't. I care about getting it working, not purity of the example on SO.

Comment: @deitch have you found an answer to your question? I'm looking to exactly the same thing

Comment: Not that I recall @FabianoTarlao. Sorry. This was a year ago, trying to recall which project it was that was using it...

Comment: Ok, I think I'll change from Golang to C++, but I'm just curious about the solution you found :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OP asked how to get the size of a *block device*. To get the size of a block device (or any file), you can File.Seek to the end of the file using io.SeekEnd and read the position returned.  Credit to others for [python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2774125/1375752) and [C](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52226/370407).

Running the example `getsize.go` below shows:

```
$ sudo go run getsize.go /dev/sda
/dev/sda is 256060514304 bytes.
```

`lsblk --bytes /dev/device` will give you the same information.  That is how much data the *block device* can store.

The `Statfs_t` path, and `df /path/to/mounted/filesystem` will give you information about how much data you can store in the *filesystem* mounted at  provided path.  Filesystems have overhead, probably in the 2-5% range depending on details of the filesystem, and also keep track of how much space is `Free` or `Used`.

There is no api that I am aware of that can provide information about unmounted filesystems on a block device.  `dumpe2fs` can give you that information for the ext{2,3,4} filesystems.  There likely exist tools for other filesystems.  Such tools are filesystem specific. When you mount the filesystem, then the linux kernel's filesystem driver exposes that information that is returned by `df`.

Code:

```
// getsize.go: get the size of a block device or file
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var path string
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        fmt.Println("Give path to file/disk")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    path = os.Args[1]
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error opening %s: %s\n", path, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    pos, err := file.Seek(0, io.SeekEnd)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error seeking to end of %s: %s\n", path, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s is %d bytes.\n", path, pos)
}
```

Comment: This is very nice. I hadn't thought of it. Is it accurate? I get slightly off numbers. https://gist.github.com/deitch/20c611e60f240eea7591bd973a0d5915

Comment: The OP asked how to get the size of a block device.  The io.Seek answer is the correct answer.  The block device in your gist can store 53686025728 bytes of data. Which is 1065472 bytes shy of 50GiB ([GiB vs GB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte)).

Comment: I updated the answer to try to explain filesystem vs block device.

Comment: your example gets me same value for system partition and mounted NAS:  `/mnt/ix4300d is 9223372036854775807 bytes. / is 9223372036854775807 bytes.` Value of NAS is wrong for me.

Answer (score 7):

When calling [`syscall.Statfs()`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Statfs), you have to pass the **path where the device is mounted**, e.g. `/`, and not the device file (not `/dev/sda1`). In your case this is `/var`.

You get the result in a value of type [`syscall.Statfs_t`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Statfs_t). Interpretation:

```
var stat syscall.Statfs_t
if err := syscall.Statfs("/", &stat); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

size := stat.Blocks * uint64(stat.Bsize)
free := stat.Bfree * uint64(stat.Bsize)
avail := stat.Bavail * uint64(stat.Bsize)
fmt.Println("Size:", size)
fmt.Println("Free:", free)
fmt.Println("Available:", avail)
fmt.Println("Used:", size-free)
```

See this possible duplicate: [Get amount of free disk space using Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108520/get-amount-of-free-disk-space-using-go)

Comment: Ah, very good point, thank you @icza. So, how would I actually get it _without_ mounting? I can do it in C with the right `ioctl` call (edited question), is there a go-native method?