# Python: Directory searching

Tags: python, file, directory

I currently have a folder with a python file sys.py.

In the same folder, I have a folder called "fsys", for file system, and I need to check what items are in the fsys folder.

*My questions*

I. How do I see what's in the folder and print it on screen?

II. How would I see how much capacity everything in the folder takes up and print it on the screen?

Thanks!

Edit: III. How would I make the list of directories perhaps blue?

My code is below:

```
usrn = "user"
cli = "konix>"
st = 1
vs = "Konix One 0.01"
# - System Declarations -
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
# - Title Declaration -
print "- K O N I X -"
print ""
print "- Konix One 0.01 -"
print ""
# - Command Reading - #
while st == 1:
    ucmd = raw_input(cli)
    cmd = ucmd.partition(' ')[0]
    if cmd == "print" or cmd == "pt":
        print ucmd.partition(' ')[2]
    if cmd == "version" or cmd == "vs":
        print vs
    if cmd == "tedit" or cmd == "td":
        if ucmd.partition(' ')[2] == "-h" or ucmd.partition(' ')[2] == "-help":
            print "Konix Tedit v1.2 Help"
            print "To open tedit, type in tedit -u in the console"
            print "You should see that your text pointer also has @tedit"
            print "To use tedit, first type in text normally."
            print "When you are done writing text, create two spaces, put a period, and press enter again."
            print "It will show you what you wrote, and you have the option to save or not."
            print "Good luck using tedit!"
        elif ucmd.partition(' ')[2] == "-u":
            input_list = []
            while True:
                input_str = raw_input("konix@tedit>")
                if input_str == "." and input_list[-1] == "":
                    break
                else:
                    input_list.append(input_str)
            for line in input_list:
                print line
            save = raw_input("Would you like to save this text to your file? [Y/N]: ")
            if save == "Y" or save == "y":
                name = raw_input("Please enter a name for this file (with .txt at the end): ")
                fsys = "fsys/"
                fsys += name
                filestring = '\n'.join(input_list)
                with open(fsys, 'w') as f:
                    f.write(filestring)
            elif save != "N" or save != "n":
                print "Not saving"
    if cmd == "list" or cmd == "ls":
        onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir("fsys") if isfile(join("fsys",f)) ]
                print os.path.join(root, file)
    if cmd == "kill" or cmd == "kl":
        print "Killing Konix - Farewell!"
        st = 0
```

Comment: Regarding #1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python?rq=1

Comment: I tried that, didn't work for me

Comment: Why didn't it work? What was the error? Also, regarding #2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-to-check-file-size-in-python

Comment: It says that the directory "/fsys" does not exist

Comment: Probably it is looking for a directory at the absolute path `/fsys`, which does not exist. Delete the `/` and see if it helps. Also, showing whatever code you have, plus whatever error messages are produced is usually very helpful to those of us with no idea what you're working on.

Comment: that is fixed but now it says "root is undefined"
it's referring to os.path.join(root, file)

Comment: Then please post the code you have. You probably have a variable called `root` somewhere and you're using it before you set it equal to something.

Comment: http://p.nanner.co/20

Comment: You need to define `root` and `file` before you use them.

Comment: how? What code would I use to define them?

Comment: The same way you would define any variable. `root = "this is a string"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty in iPython to get you going.

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: cwd = os.getcwd()

In [3]: files = os.listdir(cwd)

In [4]: files
Out[4]: ['Hello.taskpaper', 'My Todos.taskpaper', 'Tips & Tricks.taskpaper']

In [5]: os.stat(cwd)
Out[5]: posix.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=393413, st_dev=16777217L, st_nlink=5, st_uid=501, st_gid=20, st_size=170, st_atime=1388431093, st_mtime=1362280774, st_ctime=1362280774)

In [6]: for f in files:
   ...: 
Display all 324 possibilities? (y or n) 
   ...: 
   ...:     print os.stat(f)
   ...: 
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=406919, st_dev=16777217L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=501, st_gid=20, st_size=437, st_atime=1387857115, st_mtime=1341158105, st_ctime=1345503808)
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=405425, st_dev=16777217L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=501, st_gid=20, st_size=238, st_atime=1387857115, st_mtime=1350748953, st_ctime=1350783773)
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=414444, st_dev=16777217L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=501, st_gid=20, st_size=2560, st_atime=1387857115, st_mtime=1341158105, st_ctime=1345503292)
```

To see files in a subdirectory, pass in the subdirectory from the list. In my example, fsys is an empty directory. See below:

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: cwd = os.getcwd()

In [3]: files = os.listdir(cwd)

In [4]: files
Out[4]: ['fsys', 'Hello.taskpaper', 'My Todos.taskpaper', 'Tips & Tricks.taskpaper']

In [5]: files_fsys = os.listdir(files[1])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-7ca409829c27> in <module>()
----> 1 files_fsys = os.listdir(files[1])

OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'Hello.taskpaper'

In [6]: files_fsys = os.listdir(files[0])

In [7]: files_fsys
Out[7]: []
```

Now, to be clear, this is quick-and-dirty. You'd probably not hard-code the indices of the list that you're trying to access.

Comment: This was working until I noticed I couldn't get it to find the files in fsys. It showed all the files, including the fsys folder, but those aren't the files I want.

Comment: Well, here's the directory tree.

konix > sys.py
konix > fsys
I am running sys.py, and need to see the files in fsys.

How would I change into that directory?

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, are you trying to create an operating system in Python? Your code looks much like that.

Comment: Well, it may sound verily moronic, but, yes. :)

Comment: Not at all, my friend. :-) I believe it's always good to try one's hand at things.

Answer (score 2):

There is a python library called [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) that will do that kind of stuff so you don't have to re-invent the wheel. It can list files in a directory, match by extension type, etc. Lots of goodies.