# Finding the first largest file from multiple random files

Tags: python, python-2.7

def line_count(filename):

```
for filename in os.walk(os.path.abspath('my directory filename')):
    lines = 0
    with open(filename) as file:
        lines = len([line for line in file.readlines() if line.strip() != ''])
    print lines
```

def find_big_files(files):

```
file_sizes = [(line_count(file), file) for file in files] 
print sorted(file_sizes, key = lambda file_size: file_size[0], reverse = True)
```

sorted_files = find_big_files(file)

does not work.

Comment: "largest" how? In file size?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-to-check-file-size-in-python

Comment: the program should find a file with the largest lines and then list the rest of the file, for example the second largest etc...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for the LONGEST files, not the BIGGEST files, do this:

```
def get_length(file):
    len_ = 0
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        for line in f: len_+=1
    return len_

files = [file for file in however_you_build_your_list]
files = sorted(files, key=get_length)
# files[0] is now the longest
# files[-1] is now the shortest
```

Comment: what about the second largest, as per OP's request?

Comment: Whoops didn't notice that.

Comment: the program should find a file with the largest lines and then list the  second file with largest lines following the rest ....so it should not look at the file size but the content of it.

Comment: I'm after the last four lines. what do you mean by 'however build a list? the function get_length gives me a list already. Be clear please  .

Comment: `get_length` in this example does not return a list, it returns a line count. The `howoever_you_build_your_list` is referring to whatever method you have for producing a list of files to search. If that method already returned a list of files, you can just use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you counting empty lines as lines?

if so, the following gives you the number of raw newlines in a file:

```
  def line_count(filename):
      lines = 0
      with open(filename) as file:
           lines = len(file.readlines())
      return lines
```

If not, change the `lines = ...` to:

```
  lines = len([line for line in file.readlines() if line.strip() != ''])
```

So, the rest of the code would look like the following:

```
  def find_big_files(files):
      largest        = (0, None)
      second_largest = (0, None)
      for file in files:
          size = line_count(file)
          if size > largest[0]:
             second_largest = largest
             largest        = (size, file)
      return largest, second_largest
```

Note that this is really inefficient because it has to open every file and iterate across it. So it is O(file*count(file)). But if you really care about line count, not really any good way around that, at least for generic .txt files or similar.

If you want the whole list from most lines to least lines:

```
  def find_big_files(files):
      file_sizes = [(line_count(file), file) for file in files] 
      return sorted(file_sizes, key = lambda file_size: file_size[0])
```

A list of (line_count, file_name) tuples will be returned, and list[-1] will be the largest, list[-2] will be the second largest, and so on.

**EDIT:**

OP asked me to post the whole code in one block that solves the problem, so here it is:

```
  def line_count(filename):
      lines = 0
      with open(filename) as file:
           lines = len([line for line in file.readlines() if line.strip() != ''])
      return lines

  def find_big_files(files):
      file_sizes = [(line_count(file), file) for file in files] 
      return sorted(file_sizes, key = lambda file_size: file_size[0], reverse = True)
```

The return from `result = file_big_files(files)` will be `[(count, filename), ...]` from largest to smallest, so `result[0]` will be the largest, `result[1]` will be the second largest, etc. Ties will be in the original order they were in the input list of file paths.

Comment: have you tested your code? I might get it wrong but the function to find the largest and second largest do not work. because the size of the line count will always be higher than largest[0] so there will never be a second largest value. I need to double check the last function..tnx for your reply

Comment: Did you leave out the `second_largest = largest` line? That moves what was previously the largest file to the second largest file. Remember these are tuples of (count, file), not lists of files. So `largest[0]` is accessing the count element of the tuple, not the first element in a list of files. So my `first find_big_files` returns `((count, file), (count, file)`. My second example returns `[(count, file), ...]`

Comment: I did not leave out the second_largest = largest line a = 0
b = 0

tuple = 25

if tuple > than a :
 b = a  --->0
 a = tuple--->25

print a and b

print 25 and 0

so whats the point of having  b in here?? 
and how would your code find highest value than the previous? because b will always print 0

Comment: I'm confused by what you're asking. I've tested the code, it works as expected. I never do a comparison against second_largest, it's always set to be what the previous largest was when a new largest is found.

Comment: could you show me your full code that you successfully tested? i do need comparison. if you see my code on top of the page, it give me  total lines of each file which means i know the largest and second largest.

Comment: lets me re-phrase : after scanning file,my code should determine highest files in descending order or compare with the previous to find the highest before moving to the next scanning file

Comment: Which is what this code does. The first version of `find_big_files` will return only the largest and second largest, and the second version of `find_big_files` will return the whole list of files sorted by line count.

Comment: the code should FIND THE FIRST FILE with the largest lines after scanning all files. your code list files with number of lines randomly. I WANT To find the first largest FIRST. then LIST the SECOND LARGEST in--->> DESCENDING order.

Comment: 1) You should edit your question to reflect that, as it's definitely not clear from your problem statement. 2) Depending on the sort python uses (I.E. is it a [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability)), the second example will return ties of line counts in the order they appeared in the input file list.

Comment: If your code does it. Could you please show me the full code because I  cant make the last function work the second version of find_big_files

Comment: are you still testing/?

Comment: gives me Errors#TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Comment: That suggests a typo somewhere, it's trying to iterate over an uninstantiated class object. What's the full error text?

Also note that the input to `find_big_files` **must** be a list, even if you're just testing it on a single filename to see what happens.

Comment: how can I edit the code so you can see it. I believe it's something wrong with the parameter inside the function to call.  I added find_big_files(file) at end of the lines to call the function  but it doesnt seems to work.

Comment: huh? An example of the correct way to call this function would be `sorted_files = find_big_files(['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4'])`, where `fileX` is a path to a file you want to sort.

Comment: Not sure when or how you did test your code but im still having error after i fix one errors. now im getting error with file_size is not define. I cant be bother to stay all night fixing problem after another thanks anyway

Comment: Dude, I literally ran that exact code and it does exactly as promised. Perhaps if you could update your original question with what you've tried (copied and pasted) it would help us help you figure out why it's not working.

Comment: you ran exactly this code. copy and paste and it does the job ? how do you run it without calling a function? I want the full code to test what you are testing not a chunk of code I have look and puzzle...lol why do you guys always make life so hard  heh heeh

Comment: Yes, this exact code. Obviously I then proceeded to call the function as described in my comment (with actual filenames on my system obviously). These are only function definitions, they don't do anything until you call them of course.

Comment: yes I know what a function call is. that is why I have asked you if it's runs exactly as you published because if you invoke the wrong parameter from the function call it will afect all your code. that is why i asked to see all your code. the structure of your code is also very important