# Figuring out amount of computer RAM I need to open an object

Tags: python

I have a large JSON file. I need to estimate the size of the machine I need to open the file. Here is the operation that I need to do:

```
f = open('mybigfile.txt')
data = json.loads(f.read())
```

I could do `sizeof` once I have the object. However, since I don't (yet) have enough memory to get `data`, how would I estimate this?

Comment: It may technically be possible to estimate this, but doing so will require parsing the JSON (probably can't use `json`'s parser for this) and making numerous assumptions about CPython implementation details. This seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What's are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @David542 You could use the size of the file as an estimate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-to-check-file-size-in-python

Comment: _"I need to estimate the size of the machine I need to open the file."_ is your JSON file really on the several GB range ? Or are you working on very constrained embedded system ? Can't you `mmap()` the file instead of doing a plain `read()` -- broadly speaking that would decrease the required RAM by (more than) 50%...