# Python cant read file TypeError: object of type 'file' has no len()

Tags: python

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

in_file = open(from_file, 'w')


print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(in_file)

print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
raw_input()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(in_file)

print "Alright, all done."

out_file.close()
in_file.close()
```

The Error i get
TypeError: object of type 'file' has no len()

I Have set the in_file varaible to Write mode,so i do not understand where is the problem.

Comment: If you say its a duplicate maybe send a link to the "duplicate" with questions answered?

Comment: The link is in the top of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open a file in read mode then you can read file content and calculate size of content:

```
in_file = open(from_file, 'r')
f = in_file.read()
print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(f)
```

For size of file look at this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-to-check-file-size-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file in read mode.

```
in_file = open(from_file)
f =  in_file.read()
print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(f)
```