# Not able to extract image file stored in a cell to the tests where I need to attach that image

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, openpyxl, ui-automation

Following is the code I'm using to extract the image stored in G7 cell:

```
def getImageAttachment():
    ExcelBook = openpyxl.load_workbook("F:\\MSL Automation Framework\\msl.test\\TestDataExcel.xlsx")
    sheet = ExcelBook.active
    image_loader = SheetImageLoader(sheet)
    image = image_loader.get('G7')
    test_ImageAttachment = [{sheet['G6'].value: image}]
    return test_ImageAttachment
```

But  TypeError: object of type 'JpegImageFile' has no len() error is thrown when running the test. Screenshot is attached below:
[image]

Below is the screenshot attached to demonstrate image stored in G7 cell:
[image]

Please help me out. I don't want to provide image path directly to avoid hard coding and want to get the image from excel sheet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python cant read file TypeError: object of type 'file' has no len()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629536/python-cant-read-file-typeerror-object-of-type-file-has-no-len)

Comment: No @SrinivasuKaki

Comment: Are all your imported packages up to date?

Comment: Yes, they are @moken

Comment: Looks like a jpeg image which is anchored at G7 but can't see any reason for the error in code. I cannot duplicate your issue but I don't know the specifics of your sheet/image that may be causing the issue.