# OpenCv Image size, calculate size in kb

Tags: python, opencv

```
>>> import cv2
>>> img = cv2.imread("messi5.jpg", cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
>>> row, column, depth = img.shape
>>> row, column, depth
(308, 450, 3)       # Dimension is right same as reported by mac
>>> row*column*depth
415800
>>> float(row*column*depth)/1024
406.0546875
```

My mac report different size:

[image: My mac report different size:]

Comment: jpeg is a _compressed_ format. When you load the image with `imread` you have the BGR _uncompressed_ image

Comment: Whats the exact question here?

Comment: Using python it show different size and Mac report different size, any explanation??, its so clear in the post.

Comment: I think in Python OpenVC you get the size of the representation as pixels

Comment: to get the size in kb, you just need to check the [size of the file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2104080/5008845), not load the image (that decompresses from jpg and _converts_ to a BGR image)

Comment: Why you find the image size like this ? try this `float(img.size)/1024`

Comment: @RahulKP that doesn't make any sense

Comment: @Miki is right. JPG is compressed. You are calculating the amount of data that uses in memory once it is loaded and uncompressed. You may try your algorithm using an uncompressed format, however probably it will differ since the files have a header too....

Comment: `os.path.getsize(path)`