# How to selectively iterate over files with Python

Tags: python

I would like to iterate through files in a specified directory which are bigger then 100 kb and end with a *.zip.

How can this be done in a efficient way?

Will go through any zip files but not necessarily files which are bigger than 100kb;

```
for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if i.endswith(".zip"):
        ##print i
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

How can I incoprporate it in the if conditions? ie (`if i.endswith(".zip") and >100kb`). How could I used this file as an argument with `myOtherPythonScript.py`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-to-check-file-size-in-python

Comment: `os.path.getsize` will come in handy...

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this...

```
for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if i.endswith(".zip"):
        if os.path.getsize(i) > 10240:
            print i
    continue
else:
    continue
```

Comment: how would one use the file or `i`, as an argument with a called python script within that if statement? ie after the `print i` how would I used the`i` as an argument to `myOtherPythonScript.py`.

Comment: You would need to make this a class that return I and import the class in myotherpythonscript.py

Answer (score 0):

`endswith` and `os.path.getsize` are the two functions you want.

```
import os

file_names = [os.path.join(path, file_name) for file_name in os.listdir(path)]
for file_name in file_names:
    if file_name.endswith('zip') and os.path.getsize(file_name) >= 100*1024:
        pass
    else:
        pass
```