# python to check csv file size, certain sized csv file will be moved to other folder

Tags: python

i have a question:
i have many csv files in a folder and I need python to batch check file size. If file size is 17bytes, the file will be moved to a bad folder.

not sure how to check files size in a folder, and how to move files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check file size in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-to-check-file-size-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Import the 'os' package and use os.stat('your_file').st_size to get file size.