# what is the difference of the output between use getsizeof and st_size?

Tags: python-2.7

What is the difference of the output between use `getsizeof` and `st_size` ?
When I use `getsizeof` the output is `144` but when I use `st_size` is `148`. Anybody knows why this happening.

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From [How to check file size in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-to-check-file-size-in-python):

Note: the implementation of os.path.getsize is simply return os.stat(filename).st_size – wim Mar 21 '13 at 11:20

So it really should return the same...