# Looping over files with same substring

Tags: python

I have a folder containing over 485 Zipped Files. The name of each file has uniform characters with a varying date. I need to do something for files that have the same date. How can I do so? Below is a slice of the file names I have:

[image: Screenshot of the zipped files]

I basically need to run a loop through the entire list of files with sub-loops on file numbers that have the same date. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html):

```
import glob
for basefile in glob.glob('*.LOG'):
    for sub_names in glob.glob(basefile+'*'):
        # do your magic here
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Shai. It works! I am very new to python. So I apologize for asking stupid doubts. Second question: How can I compare the file size between each .LOG files and .LOG.gz_1 files for the same date? I want to be able to use LOG.gz_1 file when both the files sizes are different [on 02/02/2012 for example]?

Comment: @GauthamKanthasamy see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2104080/1714410) on getting file size in python.

Comment: Thanks @Shai. I sort of did it on my own. :)

Comment: @GauthamKanthasamy that's the best way ;)