# Python: How can I obtain the filesize of a selected file in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, size, pyqt5, filesize

In PyQt5, it is possible to select a file using QFileDialog. I understand how to obtain the file name, but how might one obtain the filesize?

Comment: Do you want to get the file size selected by QFileDialog?

Comment: If you have a filename, you can get file size via [methods from python library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-to-check-file-size-in-python). Or you need something else?

Comment: How does one in general get the size of a file? I guess that would also work here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without opening the file:

You must use the [`QFileInfo`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html) class and the [`size()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#size) method:

```
filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open file')
if filename != "":
    info = QFileInfo(filename)
    size = info.size()
    print(info)
```

Opening the file:

```
filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open file')
if filename != "":
    file = QFile(filename)
    if file.open(QFile.ReadOnly):
        print(file.size())
```

Comment: Better than a few previous answers. Implementation is something that helps more than simple explanation.

Comment: I recommend taking the time to see if the answer they propose is correct. Comments are not answers.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html):

> The file dialog has two view modes ... Detail also displays a list of file and directory names, but provides additional information alongside each name, such as the file size and modification date. Set the mode with setViewMode():

`dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);`

Comment: Ok, then you want to use `QFileInfo` on the filename