# How do I write a python test that creates an InMemoryUploadedFile from a zip file?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have the following Django code in my system:

```
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r')
for filename in zip_file.namelist():
    try:
        file_read = zip_file.read(filename)
        print(filename)
```

I am trying to test this code by passing in a zip file from a python TestCase.  When I use this code with the web interface, I noticed the zip file is an InMemoryUploadedFile type.  So I'm trying to mimic this functionality with my TestCase, but can't seem to create an InMemoryUploadedFile() in my test with a zip file.

I've tried this:

```
file_name = 'file.zip'
in_memory_uploaded_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(file_name, None, file_name, 'application/zip', 0, None, None)
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Can't you send a zip file to your api and then check ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/_modules/django/core/files/uploadedfile/#InMemoryUploadedFile) the `InMemoryUploadedFile` should be called with `InMemoryUploadedFile(file, field_name, name, content_type, size, charset, [content_type_extra])`

So, you should pass all these parameters:

```
with file as open('file.zip', 'r'):
    InMemoryUploadedFile(file, relevant_field,'arquivo',
                         'application/zip', file_size, 'utf8')
```

For file size you could use fixed number for the test, or if needed use the technique in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19079887/3930971

```
f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
size = f.tell()
f.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
```