# Python quit function if a file size is greater than 5kb

Tags: python

I'm not sure how to use the getsize method. What I'd want to do with it is to quit the program if the file size is greater that the specified size.

Comment: please show what you have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check file size in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-to-check-file-size-in-python)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you know how to get a file's size? Do you know how to quit the script? Do you know about if-statements?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the file size by using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-to-check-file-size-in-python).

```
import os, sys
if os.path.getsize("/path/isa_005.mp3") > 5000:
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method and some documentation on `stat`

```
import os
if os.stat('file.txt').st_size > 5000:
  quit()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html