# How to count symbols/bytes and make a histogram

Tags: python, plot

I have a file with a lot of text in it. This is how I read it:

```
file = open('labb9Text.txt', "r")

for lines in file:
    txt = str(lines)
    byteArr = bytearray(txt, "utf-8")
```

Now I want to write a function `makeHisto(byteArr)` that returns a *histogram*
(a list of length 256) which indicates how many times each
number/bit-pattern (0-255) occurs in byteArr. Since I am pretty new to python I do not now where to start, any suggestions how to do this? Thanks

Comment: This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-to-check-file-size-in-python ?

Comment: Consider having 256 buckets as a dict, and updating the value in the bucket as you see the next byte. `defaultdict` may be your friend.

Comment: Also, the way you

Comment: You could directly read the binary data since in your case, I think the encoding is irrelevant. Check the `'rb'` flag of Python's `open()` for that. Then, you could e.g. use numpy`s histogram function to prep the visualization, see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import sys

import requests 
from io import StringIO

import seaborn as sns # for data visualization
sns.set()

# To just take a file from https://norvig.com/big.txt
fin = StringIO(requests.get('https://norvig.com/big.txt').content.decode('utf8'))

num_symbols, num_bytes = [], []

for line in fin:
    # Get size of string in bytes.
    num_bytes.append(sys.getsizeof(line))
    # Get no. of chars in string
    num_symbols.append(len(line))

# Plot the graph.
sns.distplot(num_symbols)

# Plot the other graph.
sns.set()
sns.distplot(num_bytes)
```

Most probably, plotting them together would be more informative, try:

```
sns.distplot(num_symbols, label="chars")
sns.distplot(num_bytes, label="bytes")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [[Python 3.Docs]: class collections.**Counter**(*[iterable-or-mapping])*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) on the file contents:

> ```py
> >>> import collections
> >>>
> >>> file_name = r"C:\Windows\comsetup.log"
> >>>
> >>> with open(file_name, "rb") as fin:
> ...     text = fin.read()
> ...
> >>> len(text)
> 771
> >>>
> >>> text
> b'COM+[12:31:53]: ********************************************************************************\r\nCOM+[12:31:53]: Setup started - [DATE:12,24,2019 TIME: 12:31 pm]\r\nCOM+[12:31:53]: ********************************************************************************\r\nCOM+[12:31:53]: Start CComMig::Discover\r\nCOM+[12:31:53]: Return XML stream: <migXml xmlns=""><rules context="system"><include><objectSet></objectSet></include></rules></migXml>\r\nCOM+[12:31:53]: End CComMig::Discover - Return 0x00000000\r\nCOM+[12:31:56]: ********************************************************************************\r\nCOM+[12:31:56]: Setup (COMMIG) finished - [DATE:12,24,2019 TIME: 12:31 pm]\r\nCOM+[12:31:56]: ********************************************************************************\r\n'
> >>>
> >>> hist = collections.Counter(text)
> >>>
> >>> hist
> Counter({42: 320, 58: 38, 32: 32, 49: 26, 101: 19, 50: 17, 51: 17, 77: 16, 116: 16, 67: 14, 91: 11, 93: 11, 48: 11, 109: 11, 79: 10, 115: 10, 105: 10, 43: 9, 53: 9, 13: 9, 10: 9, 114: 9, 117: 8, 110: 8, 60: 8, 62: 8, 111: 7, 99: 7, 108: 7, 83: 5, 100: 5, 69: 5, 112: 4, 68: 4, 84: 4, 44: 4, 103: 4, 34: 4, 47: 4, 97: 3, 45: 3, 73: 3, 88: 3, 120: 3, 54: 3, 65: 2, 52: 2, 57: 2, 118: 2, 82: 2, 61: 2, 98: 2, 106: 2, 76: 1, 121: 1, 40: 1, 71: 1, 41: 1, 102: 1, 104: 1})
> >>>
> >>> chr(42).encode()  # For testing purposes only
> b'*'
> >>>
> >>> text.count(b"*")
> 320
> ```

*hist* is a mapping where each key is a byte (*[0..255]*) that was encountered in the text, and the corresponding value is its occurrences count.