# Python - Avoid saving files of 0 bytes?

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm working on a scraper that pulls down files from a website and then parses them out for the end goal. The parser keeps failing when it reaches a file of 0 bytes (as it should). Is there a way to avoid saving 0B size files when they are extracted?

I don't have a code example, but what I'm doing is creating a temp folder with `os.mkdir` and storing them there until they are parsed. I'm pulling them with `xml.etreeElementTree`. Some psuedocode:

```py
#pretend parse function is here
os.mkdir(r'C:\TEMPFILES_TO_PARSE')

for entry in filepath:
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(entry)
    #begin parse function(s)
```

tl;dr would like to not save files of 0B to avoid error flags.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-to-check-file-size-in-python might be useful. For me I simply do a check if the file len is 0 and don't run it. You could also simply have a try: except: clause to skip 0byte files.

Answer (score 1):

If your script fails when you reach a file of 0B, then you can make an if condition where you check the file size:

```
import os
file_size = os.path.getsize('yourfile.txt')

if file_size != 0:
    # do something here
```