# Check if log file has been updated / only parse new data - Python

Tags: python, parsing, logging

I have a log file and I want to check, every `n` seconds (or when it has been modified), if there are new data which have been appended to it.
I check the number of lines, if the previous count < the new, I start to parse the new data at the index = the previous line count.

```
def parse_file(path, index_to_start_parsing):
    //Parse the file

file_path = r"my_log_path"
previous_lines_count = 0
check_seconds = 5

while True:
    time.sleep(check_seconds)
    with open(file_path) as f:
        current_lines_count = sum(1 for _ in f)

    if current_lines_count > lines_count:
        data = parse_file(file_path, previous_lines_count)
        previous_lines_count = current_lines_count
```

It works, but I'm looking for a more optimized method.
How can I check if the file has changed (I read about [watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/)) **and** how can I parse only the new data appended to the file with a more efficient way.

**EDIT:**

I use `os.stat('somefile.txt').st_size` to check if the file changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `f.tell()` to discover the current offset of the file pointer when you're done reading in your initial pass.  On future passes, use `f.seek()` to advance the file pointer to that previous point in the file, and continue reading as normal.

```
offset = 0
while True:
    f = open(file)
    f.seek(offset)

    while line = f.readline():
        # process...  
        pass

    offset = f.tell()
    f.close()
    # wait until next iteration
```

This is an old C trick.

More info [here](https://thepythonguru.com/python-how-to-read-and-write-files/#random-access-using-fseek-and-ftell).

Checking if the file has been modified is usually as easy as [looking at the file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-can-i-check-file-size-in-python) and seeing if it's the same as the last time you looked.