# Is it normal that os.stat("file path").st_size returns 0 during the download process?

Tags: python

My environment:

```
Python verion: 3.8 (64 bits)
OS : Windows 10 (64 bits)
```

I need to write a program in Python that waits until a big file has been downloaded before processing its content. It's a `UTF-8` plain text file with csv extension which has been zipped. For the sake of this example we're going to name it `my_big_file.zip`. So I was searching on StackOverflow in order to see whether there has already been any suggestion in this regard and I found an interesting thread: [How can I check file size in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-can-i-check-file-size-in-python) and then I checked Python online documentation for [os.stat_result](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result)

What I have understood so far (please correct me if I'm wrong) is that `os.stat("file path here").st_size` returns the size of the given file. So I thought maybe inside a loop I can check how the size of the file is being evolved as it is being downloaded and once there is no more change that means the end of the download process. I wrote a few test programs and I debugged via pdb to see how exactly the file size evolves during the download process. This is my final solution:

```
import os


def main():
    st_size = 0

    while (st_size == 0):
        st_size = os.stat("my_big_file.zip").st_size

    print("Download terminated and the size is : {}".format(str(st_size)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What I saw while I was debugging the program via pdb was that during the entire download process every call to `os.stat("my_big_file.zip").st_size` returned 0 and only at the end of the download it returned the actual size of the file. I was rather expecting to see a gradual increase of the file size inside the loop. Therefore, my question is : in your opinion is there some bug in my code or this is indeed how `os.stat("file path here").st_size` works and returns 0 until the download has been completed? Am I on the right track and the program that I provided above is a good way for making sure that the file has been downloaded completely before proceeding?

## Edit:

If it might be helpful the file is downloaded from a website via Selenium (using Firefox web driver)

Comment: AFAIK many programs create two files, a temporary download file (e.g. in Firefox it has the extension `.part`) and the actual file with correct file name. The temporary file is used for the download and at the end the temporary file is moved but both files are created at the start of the download.

Comment: Your loop is written to terminate when `st_size == 0` is false, so it makes sense that `st_size` would always be zero inside the loop.

Comment: you can use `tqdm` module instead of reinventing the wheel

Comment: Most downloading tools use *buffered io* when writing to the disk. Depending on the OS, you will only see large increases from time to time if any. You should never rely on the size being constant for some time to assume the end of the transfert. In the opposite, the only relyable way when possible is to transfer the file with a temporary name, and rename it only when the transfert successfully completed.

Comment: @Ajay How is tqdm related to this question?

Comment: With some download programs you can assume that the download successfully completed if the file size is different to 0. Other download programs will increase the file size in steps.

Comment: @SergeBallesta OP wants "size of the file is being evolved as it is being downloaded "

Comment: @Ajay The problem is that the actual file size on the disk is 0 until completion and only changes after completion. How does a progress bar help here?

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo 

"... Your loop is written to terminate when st_size == 0 ..."

No the loop continues until st_size != 0

Comment: @Serge Ballesta "... the only relyable way when possible is to transfer the file with a temporary name, and rename it only when the transfert successfully completed ..." I don't understand what do you mean, how do you know the transfer has been completed?

Comment: @user17911: it depends on how you download the file, and you did not say...

Comment: @Serge Ballesta the file is being downloaded via Selenium

Comment: @user17911: I will not be able to help you because I do not use Selenium, but IMHO you should add it to the question itself.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta Ok. I've just added this information in my post above in the edit part.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I chose as solution what @jabaa suggested in the comments, that is, taking into account the existance of the partial file created during the download process

```
import os


def main():

    while os.path.exists("my_big_file.zip.part"):
        continue

    print("Download completed.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This works for me as we use Firefox. Indeed my previous solution that is, relying on the size of a file during the download process is not reliable based on the reasons explained in this article that I found on a blog page on Microsoft web site: [Why is the file size reported incorrectly for files that are still being written to?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111226-00/?p=8813)

Comment: This might solve your problem but it's not really an answer to the question _"Is it normal that os.stat(“file path”).st_size returns 0 during the download process?"_