# Size of all images in a list Python/shell

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a list of images.

```
Lst = ["1.jpeg", "5.jpeg", "8.jpeg", ....]
```

I want to know their individual size in Kb/MB. I am using

```sh
du - bsh <filename>
```

But The folder structure is:

```
Folder/Subfolder1/1.jpeg, 10.jpeg, ... 
Folder/Subfolder2/11.jpeg, 190.jpeg, ...
Folder/Subfolder1/5.jpeg, 90.jpeg, ...
...
```

Comment: What's the problem here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check file size in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-can-i-check-file-size-in-python)

Comment: If you are open to doing this in bash check out the ```tree``` command. You might need to install it from your package manager. 
but ``` man tree``` should give you some ideas. It shows you sub folders and aloows you to filter within them (say limit it to only JPEG files).

Comment: in Python you can use `glob.glob('*/1.jpeg', recursive=True)` to search this name in all structure. If you start in `Folder` then it will search only in its subfolders (and subsubfolders, etc.). Eventually you can use `'*.jpeg'` to get all images in all subfolders -  `glob.glob('*/*.jpeg', recursive=True)` and later check which ends with `1.jpeg`. And when you will have pathes then you can use `os.stat(path).st_size` to get size

Comment: in Python you can use `glob.glob('**/1.jpeg', recursive=True)` to search this name in all structure. You can even use `'Folder/**/1.jpeg'` to search only in `Folder`. Eventually you can use `'*.jpeg'` to get all images in all subfolders -  `glob.glob('**/*.jpeg', recursive=True)` and later check which ends with `1.jpeg`, `5.jpeg`, etc. And when you will have pathes then you can use `os.stat(path).st_size` to get size.

Comment: Do you mean Kb, kB or kiB? In any case, it's not clear where your problem is. I guess the nudge in the right direction is to split the task, one is to locate the files, the other to retrieve the size of one and then finally the combination of both. In any case, please read the description of tags you applied, both "shell" and "linux" are rather bad choices.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can get file size using `stat()`

```
os.stat(path).st_size
```

And you can find file(s) using `glob.glob` with `*`, `?` or `**`.

```
files = glob.glob("Folder/*/1.jpeg")

for path in files:
    print(path, os.stat(path).st_size)
```

It always gives list with all matching paths - even if found only one file or it didn't find any file.

If it may have file in `Folder/sub1/sub2/sub3/1.jpeg` then you can use `**` and recursion

```
files = glob.glob("Folder/**/1.jpeg", recursive=True)
```

Of course you can use string formating (`.format()` or `f-string`) to search different files from list

```
for name in Lst:
    files = glob.glob(f"Folder/**/{name}", recursive=True)
```

Or you can use `*.jpeg` to get all files and later check if it on the list

```
files = glob.glob("Folder/**/*.jpeg", recursive=True)

for path in files:
    filename = path.split('/')[-1]
    if filename in Lst:
        print(path, os.stat(path).st_size)
```

---

**EDIT:**

In `Bash` you can also use `*`

```
for path in Folder/*/*.jpeg 
do 
   du -bsh $path 
done
```

or in one line

```
for path in Folder/*/*.jpeg; do du -bsh $path; done
```

but it still needs to filter files which are on list.

But maybe it could be simpler to use `{ }`

```
for path in Folder/*/{1,5,8,10,11}.jpeg
```

For more help in Bash you could ask on similar portals: [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)